# assign pseudoclass to a label within a specific div

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I would like to assign a pseudo-css class to a `<label>` within a div with a a specific `#id`

My markup:

```
<div id="square">
  <input class="time" id="show_45min" type="checkbox" name="time" value="45min">
  <label for="show_45min" class="square">45 min</label><br>

  <input class="time" id="show_60min" type="checkbox" name="time" value="60min">
  <label for="show_60min" class="square">60 min</label><br>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#square input[type=radio] {  
  display: none;  
}  

#square label:before {  
  content: "";  
  display: inline-block;  
  width: 16px;  
  height: 16px;  
  margin-right: 10px;  
  position: absolute;  
  left: 0;  
  bottom: 1px;  
  background-color: #aaa;  
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);  
}
```

problem is, that still every `label` on the page gets the content of `label:before`. But I just want it to assign to the labels within the div.

Thanks

Comment: Given the code above, this should work- its likely to do with unposted code

Comment: #square > label:before {
       //your css
    }

Comment: The label would need `position:relative` which might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/luhib/1/edit

```
input[id^=show_]{
  display:none;
}
label[for^=show_]:before {  
  content: "";  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  width: 1em;  
  height: 1em;  
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #aaa;  
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);  
}
input[id^=show_]:checked + label.square:before {  
 box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 15px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);  
}
```

Comment: you got me, exactly what I wanted. :) edit: you should get extra points for reading my mind that I just wrapped the div around to target only that specific labels!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the **>** direct child selector:

```
#square > label:before
```

**[More from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)**

> The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those
>   elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of
>   elements matched by the first. By contrast, when two selectors are
>   combined with the descendant selector, the combined selector
>   expression matches those elements matched by the second selector for
>   which there exists an ancestor element matched by the first selector,
>   regardless of the number of "hops" up the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
#square label:before
```

to

```
#square > label:before
```